# bash if statement with command and sys var

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement, command

For info, I'm on solaris 9, using a bash script.
Running the script manually works fine, but via cron, he can't get past
the first verification:

```
if [ `/usr/bin/echo $MACHTYPE | grep -i "solaris"` ];then
```

I tried with dozens of variations. But none seem to work.
I could just skip that part but I'll have similar problems later on and this if statement is interesting because it contains a command using a system variable. I tried another version in which I compare the output with a string (maybe more difficult?) but I'm stuck.

If someone could bring some light on what to use and where: ( [ ' "
because sometimes [[ isn't recognized. All the variations are based on what I found here and elsewhere. It seems the formatting possibilities are huge.
( I left out the other 'then echo .. fi')

```
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if ['/usr/bin/echo $MACHTYPE == "solaris"']
> then echo "hello"
> fi
bash: [/usr/bin/echo $MACHTYPE == "solaris"]: No such file or directory
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if ['/usr/bin/echo $MACHTYPE == 'solaris'']    
bash: [/usr/bin/echo $MACHTYPE == solaris]: No such file or directory
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if ["/usr/bin/echo $MACHTYPE == 'solaris'"] 
bash: [/usr/bin/echo solaris == 'solaris']: No such file or directory
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if ["$MACHTYPE == 'solaris'"]\             
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if ["$MACHTYPE == 'solaris'"] 
bash: [solaris == 'solaris']: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if ['$MACHTYPE == 'solaris'']     
bash: [$MACHTYPE == solaris]: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if ['$MACHTYPE == solaris']  
bash: [$MACHTYPE == solaris]: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if ["$MACHTYPE == solaris"] 
bash: [solaris == solaris]: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if [["$MACHTYPE" == "solaris"]]              
bash: [[solaris: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if [[$MACHTYPE == solaris]]      
bash: [[solaris: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if [["$MACHTYPE" == solaris]]
bash: [[solaris: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if [["/usr/bin/echo $MACHTYPE" == solaris]]
bash: [[/usr/bin/echo solaris: No such file or directory
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if [[($MACHTYPE) == solaris]]   
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `[[($MACHTYPE)'
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if [[($MACHTYPE) == solaris]]
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `[[($MACHTYPE)'
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if [["/usr/bin/echo $(MACHTYPE)" == solaris]]
bash: MACHTYPE: command not found
bash: [[/usr/bin/echo : No such file or directory
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if [["$(MACHTYPE)" == solaris]]              
bash: MACHTYPE: command not found
bash: [[: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if ["$(MACHTYPE)" == solaris]  
bash: MACHTYPE: command not found
[: missing `]'
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if [$(MACHTYPE) == solaris]  
bash: MACHTYPE: command not found
[: missing `]'
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if [[ $(echo $MACHTYPE) == solaris]]; then         
bash: [[: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if (( $(echo $MACHTYPE) == solaris)); then    
bash: solaris: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if (( $(echo /$MACHTYPE) == solaris)); then
> echo "hello"
> fi
bash: /solaris: No such file or directory
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if (( $(echo /$MACHTYPE) == solaris)); then
> 
> fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf/bin/scripts] $ if (( $($MACHTYPE) == solaris)); then      
bash: solaris: command not found
bash: ==: command not found

[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf] $ if (( $(echo \$MACHTYPE) == solaris)); then 
bash: $MACHTYPE: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf] $ if (( $('echo \$MACHTYPE') == solaris)); then
> echo "hello"
> fi
bash: echo \$MACHTYPE: command not found
bash: ==: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf] $ if (( $('echo $MACHTYPE') == solaris)); then 
bash: echo $MACHTYPE: command not found
bash: ==: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf] $ if (( $('/usr/bin/echo $MACHTYPE') == solaris)); then
bash: /usr/bin/echo $MACHTYPE: No such file or directory
bash: ==: command not found
[mvf@odin:/usr/mvf] $ if (( $(/usr/bin/echo $"MACHTYPE") == solaris)); then 
bash: $MACHTYPE: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different solutions to pass the variables to cron, but only one did work:

creating a .cronfile with declaration of the variables and then
source the files directly in the script that is run by cron:
( i also declared the PATH in the script because the cron PATH is not complete)

```
. $HOME/.cronfile
rest of the script
```

so no syntax problems :)

Thanks dangenet!

Answer (score 1):

Using bash globbing:

```
if [[ $MACHTYPE = *solaris* ]]; then
```

Using regex:

```
if [[ $MACHTYPE =~ solaris ]]; then
```

Pure sh solution:

```
case $MACHTYPE in
    *solaris*)
        echo "Yes, it is solaris"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "No, something else"
        ;;
esac
```

And finally the worst solution:

```
if /usr/bin/echo "$MACHTYPE" | grep -i 'solaris'; then
```

Also it is `/bin/echo` for me, but just `echo` should work as well.

Seems like bruteforcing doesn't work for you, so you'd better read all of these:
[Bash Guide: Tests and Conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals)
[Bash hackers: test command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)
[Bash hackers: conditional expressions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression)

Comment: The problem is the sys vars not passing through. I tried bash globbing already. But thanks for the info ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that your line

```
if [ `/usr/bin/echo $MACHTYPE | grep -i "solaris"` ];then echo "hello"; fi
```

works when you run it yourself but not when cron runs the script. That implies that your line is ok, and in fact it works for me in a login shell.

So what is different about cron running it?

There is [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work?lq=1) about reasons cron fails. The one I have in mind is that cron requires explicit paths for everything, including grep. So you might need /bin/grep instead of grep. If that's not it, I hope that something in there is helpful.

All that said Aleks' test expression is more appealing. Let us know what fixes your problem.